# React-Navigation: How to implement multi-independant viewstacks with react-navigation (React-Native)

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

Good morning, good afternoon or good evening

I want to archive this navigation interface (for desktop / tablet screen size):
https://photos.app.goo.gl/ZEna1uozQP1UnVWm6

Each viewstack should be fully dependent to only one navigation; I am using react-navigation.

However, with my following code, the the pane view (the card) is completely hidden / gone on the main page.

How should I do this in order to archive the results on the prototype / video.

Below are my codes.

Thank you!

**App.js (Main navigation)**

```
import React, { FC } from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

import { ThemeProvider } from '@emotion/react';
import setTheme from '@lib/theme';
import changeNavigationBarColor from 'react-native-navigation-bar-color';

import {
  Home as Billing,
  Customers,
} from '@components/5-pages';

const theme = setTheme('light');
const Stack = createStackNavigator();
changeNavigationBarColor("black", false, true);

type Props = {};

const App: FC<Props> = ({...props}) => {

    return (
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName={"billing"} screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>

            <Stack.Screen name="billing" component={ Billing } />
            <Stack.Screen name="customers" component={ Customers } />

            </Stack.Navigator>
          </NavigationContainer>
      </ThemeProvider>
    );

};

export default App;
```

**Card.js (Pane / Inner navigation)**

```
import React, { FC }from 'react';
import styled from '@emotion/native';
import Text from './Text';
import setTheme from '@lib/theme';


import { NavigationContainer, useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@emotion/react';


const Container = styled.View`
    background: ${({ theme }: any) => theme.colors.white };
    border-radius: 6px;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    margin: 6px 12px;
    width: 320px;
`;

const Content = styled.View`
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-left: 6px;
`;

const Title = styled(Text)`
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #404040;
    line-height: 49px;
`;

const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const theme = setTheme('light');

const Card: FC<Props> = ({ children, modal, title, ...props }) => {

  const List : FC<Props>= ()  =>  {
    const navigation = useNavigation();

    return (
      <Container {...props} >
        <Title>{title}</Title>

        <Content onModal={()=>{navigation.push("modal", props)}}>
          {children}
        </Content>

      </Container>
    )};

    const Modal : FC<Props>= ()  =>  {
      return (
        <Container {...props} >
          <Title>{title}</Title>
  
          <Content>
            {modal}
          </Content>
  
        </Container>
      )};

  return (
      <NavigationContainer independent={true}>
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName={"list"} screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>

          <Stack.Screen name="list" component={ List } />
          <Stack.Screen name="modal" component={ Modal } />

          </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
  );
}


type Props = {
  title?: string;
  children?: React.ReactNode;
  modal?: React.ReactNode;
};

export default Card;
```

Comment: I you wanna implement a master detail view you checkout this sample https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/main/example/src/Screens/MasterDetail.tsx

Comment: @MichaelBahl Hello and thank you for reaching out.

I have followed your link. And the example only implement a Drawer.  

What I want is have two `NavigationContainer` in my app. 

With my code, the content of the Card, which render as second `NavigationContainer`, flick and disappear in about a second.

Comment: Why you wanna nest NavigationContainer? Can’t you just nest navigators?

Comment: I want the `Card`, in the prototype video with the title "Payments", to have its own Navigation interface.

Hence, I will be able to navigate to different pages but within the Card only.

You can see the video here: https://photos.app.goo.gl/ZEna1uozQP1UnVWm6